# Don't need to close the antd Modal after Clicking "Save and Add" Button and need to close after clicking "Save and Close"

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd Modal.
I have two buttons.

- Save and Add - Don't want to close the modal on clicking this.(This is not working)
- Save and Close -Want to close the modal on clicking this.

But, when clicking both buttons it's closing. I don't need that

index.js

```
this.state = {
            isOpen: false,
}
handleCancel = () => {
        this.setState({isOpen:false});
    };
handleAddModal = () => {
        var self = this;
        this.setState({isOpen:true,isEdit:false,CompanyID:this.state.CompanyID,selectedItem:null,fields: {
            RegisterID: { value: '',},
            CustomerID: { value: '',},
            AccountID: { value: '',},
        }});  
    };
handleSave = (state) => {
        this.setState({
            isOpen:state.isOpen
        });
    };
<RegisterForm 
                showLoader={this.showLoader} 
                visible={this.state.isOpen} 
                />
```

RegisterForm.js

```
this.state={saveOrClose:false}
handleClear = () => {
        this.props.form.resetFields()
    };
    handleCancel = () => {
        this.props.handleCancel()
    };

handleSubmit = (e,isNewAdd) => {
        this.setState({saveOrClose:isNewAdd})
           let val = Object.assign({'CompanyID':this.props.CompanyID.value},values);
           this.props.actions.register.AddRegister(val);
           if(!isNewAdd){
           this.handleClear();
           this.props.handleSave(false);}

    });
  };
render(){
<Modal
                    visible={visible}
                    title=
                    "Register Form"
                    className="dialog-container"
                    onCancel={this.handleCancel}
                    footer={[
                        <Button className="save-btn" onClick={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event,true)} 
                        style={{'visibility' : this.props.RegisterID.value === '' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}}>Save and Add </Button>,

                        <Button className="save-btn" onClick={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event,false)}>
                        {this.props.isEdit ?  "Save" :"Save and Close"  }</Button>, //Edit Button 

                        ]}>
}
```

I tried to write a condition by passing a boolean value on `onClick` function of the Button.

How to code this actually so that I get the desired result?
Is there any mistake in the logic?
Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example on codesandbox. As is, the code above isn't enough to track down your issue. Please start by forking this ant design codesandbox template: https://codesandbox.io/s/wk04r016q8

Answer (score 0):

```
 handleSubmit = (e,isNewAdd) => {
        this.setState({saveOrClose:isNewAdd})
           let val = Object.assign({'CompanyID':this.props.CompanyID.value},values);
           this.props.actions.register.AddRegister(val);
           if(!isNewAdd){
           this.handleClear();
           this.props.handleSave(false);}

    });
  };
```

Comment: please update code, I dont see in code where bool flag is working, it not trigged anywhere

Comment: I update my answer, you Make setState, and then compare with state.saveOrClose, it will not work because setState work asynchronously

Comment: Still not woking

Comment: updated the code as per your answer . but not working

Comment: Please find the updated code in the above code @egorchik